# Have Excel's Correlation Function Respect Filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a cell that's using the CORREL function to return the correlation of two rows of data in my spreadsheet.  The issue is that I'd like this to update based on the filter that I have applied.

I'm using the SUBTOTAL function to do this for other functions such as SUM and AVERAGE.  How can I get my correlation function to do the same thing and respect the filter that I have applied?

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple with only SUBTOTAL function. The only way is to add a column of products between the two columns (columns, not rows) of data, and then calc correlation as a function of SUBTOTAL functions.